# Select box duplicates as I click on Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<!--button to open modal-->
<a id="btn_bay_chart" onclick="showBayChart(<?php echo $jobcard_id; ?>)" class="btn btn-success pull-right btn-sm" >View Bay Chart</a>

<!--modal container-->
<div class="modal-container"></div>

<!--function to open modal-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showBayChart(jobcard_id){
        var url = "bay-chart.php?jobcard_id="+jobcard_id;
        $('.modal-container').load(url,function(result){
            $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
        });
    }
</script>

<!--chosen-select box-->
<select class="form-control chosen-select" id="job_type_id" name="job_type_id">
    <option value="">Select Job Type</option>
    <?php
    $qry_job = "SELECT DISTINCT(job_type_name), job_type_id from tbl_job_types WHERE dealership_id = '$dealership_id' AND status=1 ORDER BY job_type_name";
    $res_job = mysqli_query($link,$qry_job);
    while($row_job = mysqli_fetch_array($res_job,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        if($row_job['job_type_id']==$row['job_type_id'])
            echo "<option value='$row_job[job_type_id]' selected >$row_job[job_type_name]</option>";
        else
            echo "<option value='$row_job[job_type_id]'>$row_job[job_type_name]</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

I am using **gentelella-master** template and **chosen-Select** plugin. On my page I have a form and button. When i click on button(View Bay Chart) a modal pops up and add a row to the form on my page with select element. Every time I click the modal the row gets added. I don't know if this issue is due to **chosen-select** plugin or **modal** or **gentelella-master** template causing it. Please guide me what could be the possible reasons that are causing the select to repeat itself after every click on Modal button(View Bay Chart). Screenshot are attached. I have included code of modal, show function for modal and Select element code.
[image]

Comment: First post your code .

Comment: @NimeShPatel I edited my answer.

Comment: look if there is a click event behind your `modal` allocate button

Comment: Issue resolved. Thankyou fellow coders for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got the reason. I was including the plugin to both create file of form and modal. Thus, the plugin was being called on the same page with the modal every time I open the modal.